# Why does pointwise convergence of a function not imply convergence of the integral of that function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The question asks:
If $f_n\to f$ pointwise, then $\int f_n \to \int f$, where I have to provide a proof or a counter example. 
I know that it is not true, and hence I must provide a counter example, but how might I go about doing this?

Comment: What if you consider $\int_0^{\infty}$ and $f=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)= \frac 1x$ for $1 \leq x \leq n+1, - \frac {1}{x-n}$ for $n+1 \lt x \leq 2n+1$, and $0$ for $x \lt 1$ and $x \gt 2n+1$.

Then $\int f_n = 0$ but $f_n \to \frac 1x$ for $x \geq 1, 0$ for $x \lt 1$ pointwise.

Comment: Great, thank you! Convergence of a sequence of integrals can be guarenteed under some additional hypothesis. Would i be right in saying this holds if $(f_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions? (from monotone convergence theorem)

Comment: As long as the functions are increasing and measurable, I don't think you need them to be non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  $$f_n(x)=\max\{0,2n-|n^2x-n|\} $$
on $[0,2]$.

Comment: Great, thank you! Convergence of a sequence of integrals can be guarenteed under some additional hypothesis. Would i be right in saying this holds if $(f_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions? (from monotone convergence theorem)